# Retrieving the deleted ticket in Jira software

Tags: jira

I have deleted a ticket in my Jira project. But I want to retrieve that so that it can be available at same stage and same place like earlier in that. Is that possible? If yes please help me to do that.

Thanks
 sandeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't any backup then you can't restore issues.

But if you have any backup with necessary data you can use this method:
[How to restore accidentally deleted issue in JIRA applications](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-restore-accidentally-deleted-issue-in-jira-applications-313466155.html).

Answer (score 3):

Deleted JIRA issues are lost and you can't retrieve them.